# Why can't I create a payment processor in multisite?

Tags: drupal, payment-processor, multisite, 5.1.0

I have a multisite setup with a payment processor defined in one site. When I try to create one in the other site, it does not save and I get this error: "Expected one PaymentProcessor but found 2".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the same payment processor naming for both? You must give it a unique name.